# Get text given the bounding box coordinates

Tags: ocr, python-tesseract

I have a machine learning model trained for a custom data set that provides bounding boxes for specific portions of an image that contain text that I am interested in. I am trying to see if I can perform OCR on the bounding box and retrieve the chunk of text contained within the bounding box using Tesseract. Can someone point me in the right direction to obtain the text, given the bonding box?